# Display user inputs from a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to write a program that prompts users to enter positive integers with a sentinel value of -1. The program needs to display the entered integers on a single line (excluding the -1), then show the sum of the entered integers. I've done some searching and it looks like I need to create a list to store the numbers in I think? I'm pretty new still and don't really know how to do that. I tried googling but it just left me confused. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter positive integers. Enter -1 to stop. ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        while (number != -1) {
            if (number < -1) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            } else
                sum += number;
            number = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The sum: " + sum + ".");
    }
}
```

By the way this is my first time submitting so sorry if I've done something wrong!

Comment: Here's the tutorial on collections: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/. But you don't need a list of integers to do that. You can simply create a String and concatenate the read numbers to the string, and then print the string after the last number has been entered.

Comment: Put the numbers into an ArrayList or similar container, then just iterate over the numbers in the end.

Comment: Dude this stuff is confusing me so much right now.

Comment: @Richard The problem with asking a broad question like this is there's a million ways to do it, and each way has it's own pluses/problems. What part are you specifically asking about?

Comment: I see, sorry about that. This is for a programming class. Here is the wording of the assignment: "Design and implement a Java program (name it InputSum) that prompts the user to enter a positive integer number. The program should accept integers until the user enters the value -1 (negative one).
After the user enters -1, the program should display the entered numbers followed by their sum."

Comment: The only part I don't have is displaying the entered numbers. No limit on the amount of entered numbers, just need to take the entered numbers and print them on a single line.

Comment: You received a link to a tutorial explaining how to use collections, a suggestion on how to avoid using lists and still achieve the desired result and, if that weren't enough already, a complete response doing your homework for you. It's now time to try something based on all this information.

Comment: Yes JB Nizet I understand that, I'm still reading through the tutorial. I'm trying, but this is all new to me, so I'm sorry that I'm not learning it all as fast as you think I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way using a [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter positive integers. Enter -1 to stop. ");
        int number = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do{
            try {
                number = scan.nextInt();

                if(number < -1){
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                }else if(number > -1){
                    sum += number;
                    sb.append(number + " ");
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) { // handle invalid integers
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            }
        }while (number != -1);

        System.out.println("Numbers entered: " + sb.toString().trim() + ".");
        System.out.println("The sum: " + sum + ".");
    }
}
```

This will iterate until the user enters -1. Finally it will show the sum of your positive integers and the numbers entered. I'm using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to accumulate the numbers. You could use a list as you have said also, but I find this way easier.

**EDIT**

Here is another way to do it without the try-catch block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter positive integers. Enter -1 to stop. ");
        int number = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do{
            if(scan.hasNextInt()){
                number = scan.nextInt();

                if(number < -1){
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                }else if(number > -1){
                    sum += number;
                    sb.append(number + ", ");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                scan.next(); // reset the scanner
            }
        }while (number != -1);

        System.out.println("Numbers entered: " + sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length()) + ".");
        System.out.println("The sum: " + sum + ".");
}
```

As mentioned in the comments this time I'm using [hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) to validate if the input is a valid integer before reading it. This is to prevent exceptions that would be thrown if the user enters invalid integers. I have also separated the numbers with commas.

Comment: Do I have to use the try-catch part if I use the string builder? We haven't gone over that in class so I'm not sure he will accept it if it has that.

Comment: @Richard the try-catch block it's just to prevent undesirable results if the user enters a non-valid integer (like 4.65, ten, 2o). In those cases the method [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) in the scanner class throws an `InputMismatchException`. An alternative to the try-catch block could be using the method [hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) to evaluate the input before reading the value with the `nextInt` method

Comment: @Richard It's used to handle bad input by the user. Really, your first example should use it, but if they haven't taught it yet, I'd leave it out. If the user enters bad input, your program will crash. The try...catch prevents that.

Comment: @Richard Also for your own sake, *please* don't copy and paste this. Make sure you understand each part, and manually write it out from scratch.

Comment: Gotcha. I put the string builder into my code and it's working! I didn't copy/paste, just used the string building parts. Didn't mess with the try-catch stuff. The example given on my assignment includes commas so I'm going to play around with it using trial & error to see if I can get the commas in there, but thank you to you and Juan, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuilder to store the numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputSum {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter positive integers. Enter -1 to stop. ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (number != -1) {
        if (number < -1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
        } else
            sum += number;
        number = scan.nextInt();
        sb.append(number + " +  ");
    }
    System.out.println("The sum: " + sum + ".");
}
```

}